# Why am I getting a "TS 1128" on my If/else statement writing in JavaScript on VS Code version 1.52

Tags: javascript, if-statement, visual-studio-code

[This is a picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te3Vh.png)

Hello,

I'm very new to coding, it's safe to assume I know nothing. I am trying to complete a practice exercise from the book, JavaScript and JQuery by Jon Duckett. It is the very first exercise that is showing how there are layers to a webpage, starting with HTML, then CSS, and finally JavaScript. I am writing JavaScript code in Visual Studio Code, and am getting red squiggly lines under the "else" portion of my if/else statements. The error code I'm seeing is "TS 1128", which says "Declaration or statement expected".

From the research I am doing to figure out what is wrong, I'm seeing that I may need to download an extension or possibly change the settings of one of the extensions I already have? I'm doing a "career path" on Codecademy, and it had me download 3 extensions when I downloaded VS Code (ESLint, Prettier, and npm). I've spent several hours trying to figure this out, and am beyond frustrated at this point. Any help would be so greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please post your code as text, not a link to a painting of it. You can [edit] your question to include the code with [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Apologize for the incorrect formatting. It was my first question, and I'm not familiar with the format that's preferred. Someone else was able to ascertain an answer for me based on my original post, so I will forgo editing.

Comment: Improving the formatting of the question without changing its content (in a way that would invalidate the answer) is still an improvment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control flow (if else) does not require statement terminators (`;`).

Pay attention to the semi colons.
It should look like this:

```
if (true) {

} else if (false) {

} else {

}
```

And not like this:

```
if (true); {

} else if (false); {

} else; {

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Slava! This solved the problem. Got carried away with the semicolons.